# delay in getting complete boolean callback of UIView block animation (animateWithDuration)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-animation, xcode4.2

i am doing block animation, my project is using opengl for gameplay and uiview for menu like stuff.

i am animating uiview using animateWithDuration method, bt facing issue at getting delay  complete animation boolean callback. I tried the same code in UIKit app and it works very smoothly.

Below is my code:

```
-(void) playAnimation:(UIButton *)_button atPosition:(CGRect)_rect withDuration:(CGFloat)_duration andDelay:(CGFloat)_delay andDiection:(NSInteger)_direction
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:_duration
                          delay:_delay
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear     
                     animations:^{ 
                         _button.frame = _rect;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut     
                                          animations:^{ 
                                              CGRect rect = _rect;

                                              rect.origin.x = _rect.origin.x + (10 * _direction); 
                                              _button.frame = rect;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                                                                    delay:0.0
                                                                  options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut     
                                                               animations:^{ 
                                                                   _button.frame = _rect;
                                                               }
                                                               completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                                               }];

                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: A keyframe animation may make more sense than nesting blocks.

Comment: whats wrong with block animation? it works fine with uikit app, then why not in opengl app ?

Comment: gerry3,  i tried keyframe animation, it works fine but the issue is it get invisible after completion...any help ?

Comment: in the above code i am getting "Segmentation Fault" error, if i comment "_button.frame = _rect;" the error get resolve, but i need this code as i am setting the position to middle of the screen. Why cant i access _button and _rect in 3rd block. Those are accessible in 2nd block...is it the limitatuion of block animation?

Comment: Are you running on the main thread? Are you managing memory properly (I assume you are using ARC)? For the keyframe animation, I think you will want to set the final position in a completion block/method. Otherwise, it will revert to the starting position (what you are calling "get invisible").